# Pomodoro technique timer/assistant for Windows

Tags: windows, productivity

I would like to find good tool for [Pomodoro technique](http://pomodorotechnique.com/) for Windows.

Requested features:

- supports short and long breaks

  - good if NOT forcing user into single fixed scheme of breaks (3 short, 1 long)
- supports task list

  - export of data would be welcome
- history of pomodoro acitivities
- can be switched to smaller form to save screen estate, still remaining always-on-top
- hotkeys support

  - start, stop, make note etc.

Currently I'm using [Pomodairo](http://code.google.com/p/pomodairo/), but I'm not happy I can't specify whether short or long break will follow. I'm seeking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

#### Pomodairo

free tool written in Adobe Air

standard view: [image]

compact view: [image]

few mins later: [image]

**Pros:**

- elegant
- shrinkable
- with task list
- free

**Cons:**

- needs Adobe Air runtime
- supports only fixed scheme of breaks – you can't have long break when you want to. If something happens, you cannot manually adjust which break follows.